# UIView.animateKeyframes not working properly after iOS 15 update

Tags: ios, swift

I have UITableView that update rapidly via WebSocket and RXSwift. Every update will play flash animation. Everything works well in iOS11 - iOS14 but after the iOS15 update, the animation has weird behavior. It isn't play properly. It skip most of animation updates. Sometime it play animation in all rows at the same time.

**Edited:** I've got another issue; when I press on the button in the cell, the action didn't fire. It take a lot of click on it to make it fired, looks like it can't touch the button while updating. Sometime I press on button in cell 1 but the action fired as cell 2 context.

(Cell information was hidden for secret)

[image]

From the video, on the left was run on iOS11-iOS14. The animation works smoothly while on the right the animation was skipped.

The code to update the animation is:

```swift
    func flash()->Observable<Void>{
        return Observable.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: []){
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.background.alpha = 0
                }
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.background.alpha = 0.2
                }
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.background.alpha = 0
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

Call it like this. I didn't dispose someBehaviorRelay because it removes the animation

```
    someBehaviorRelay.subscribe { [unowned self] value in
        flash().subscribe().disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

And I reassign disposeBage when reuse

```swift
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
```

Is there any suggestion for me to solve this problem? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

**I found the solution is use reconfigure instead of reloadData for UITableView**

```swift
    // if iOS15
    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!
    if !indexPaths.isEmpty {
        tableView.reconfigureRows(at: indexPaths)
    } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation why is reconfigureRows working and reloadData isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution already, updated in the question.

Comment: Is cell for row called when you call reconfigure rows?